# If a value is between an interval, select the value on the same row in another column

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
        s     gamma_star    
0   0.000000    0.6261
1   0.000523    0.6262  
2   0.000722    0.6263  
3   0.000861    0.6267  
4   0.000972    0.6269  
5   0.001061    0.6260  
6   0.001147    0.6263  
7   0.001218    0.6261
```

I have a value `s = 0.000871`, what I need to look for is the related gamma_star that belongs to this `s`. In the example above it would be `s` is between `3   0.000861    0.6261` and `4   0.000972    0.6261` then it's related `gamma_star` is `0.6267`! I am a bit stuck and do not know how to sart, any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.loc[(df.s > s).idxmax()-1, 'gamma_star']
# 0.6267
```

Where the use condition will be indicating the starting point on which the condition is satisfied

```
(df.s > s)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: s, dtype: bool
```

and by taking the [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) we can find the beginning of the interval:

```
(df.s > s).idxmax()-1
# 3
```

Comment: Yes, but it looks like OP wants the index from the first  value from `gamma_star ` in the interval. So as I understand it you only have to find the beginning of the interval

Comment: yes indeed the value at the beginning of the interval! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a loop, if you go through the s-values.

```
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if given_value > s[i] and given_value < s[i+1]:
        gamma_s_wanted = gamma_star[i]
        break
    else:
        gamma_s_wanted = gamma_star[-1]
```